# Question on replace of Inductor Coil in a FM Transmitter

Tags: inductor, transmitter, coil

I am making a 2 Watt FM transmitter. The transmitter's inductor is somewhat like this :-

[image]

The resistor is part of the transmitter circuit. I am little confused with the inductor and not sure how to make it. I have small ferrite toroid. Will it work?

And 0.8mm CuAg wire means 20AWG. If I replace it with #23 or #26 wire, how many turns would be applicable? For L2, would a normal insulated copper wire work? And should it overlap L1 on the ferrite, or co-exist on the ferite beside L1?

I am referring the below circuit:

[image]

Any idea, if L1 and L2 can be replaced with a single air-core Copper Coil?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the inductor in the 2nd schematic **is** a single core inductor ! Well not really, it is actually a **transformer**.

The connection to the antenna is part of the inductor. Actually that inductor is a transformer, the primary side has a centertap, the secondary side is connected to that centertap and the other connection goes to the antenna.

It would have been more clear if this symbol was used:

[image]

But then without the core !
T1 and T2 connect to top and bottom right, mid-right and bottom left connect to battery voltage, top left is the antenna output.

This is a configuration that is used to connect the **differential signal**, present at the collecors of T1 and T2, to a **single ended** antenna.

Comment: Sorry @FakeMoustache I am actually referring this circuit (my bad, I posted the similar circuit by mistake): http://educypedia.karadimov.info/library/fm2w.gif which is a similar version of the above one and describes 2 lines on the inductor. So is it a regular transformer? I believe, a normal transformer has way more inductance than what is required in a FM transmitter. Isn't it?

Comment: *So is it a regular transformer?* What is a **regular transformer** ?? Maybe you're thinking of a **mains transformer** ? Of course these need more windings as the operating frequency is a lot lower (50 or 60 Hz). A transformer at 100 MHz (or even 100 GHz) is still a transformer, it might have less windings, it will have less inductance, it might not have a magnetic core. But it is still a transformer.

Comment: The way this new circuit is drawn is **confusing** as it is unclear from the schematic that there needs to be **magnetic coupling**  from L2 to L1. The bottom connection of L1 is the battery voltage. **It has no RF signal**. So making L1 a separate coil makes the circuit **transmit nothing** ! The way the RF signal is fed to the antenna is by the magnetic coupling between L1 and L2, which is invisible in the circuit, making it a confusing drawing. Sure it is mentioned in the text but who reads that ?

Comment: No @FakeMoustache there was no text describing the coil. Unfortunately!
That's why I am seeking help. Please can you guide me a little to complete the coil. How to achieve magnetic coupling from L1 to L2 in this case?

And yes, I thought it to be a mains transformer. Thanks, you made it clear.

Comment: *How to achieve magnetic coupling from L1 to L2 in this case?* Read the textbox, it says: L2 is 2-4 turns of insulated copper wire **wound over L1**. You wind L1, then you wind L2 over it.

Comment: Hi @FakeMoustache, I understood that part from the diagram's legend. My question is - since you said that the diagram is confusing and L1 is connected to +ve which probably should not be, I was curious to know what exactly the 2 ends of L1 coil  should be connected to, in order to achieve magnetic coupling.

Comment: The connections of L1 are OK !!! (Although I would connect one side to ground instead of +Ve but that is personal preference) The magnetic coupling **has nothing to do how you connect it**. The magnetic coupling is achieved **by winding L1 OVER L2**. That's it !! Also read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_coupling magnetic coupling is a different word for inductive coupling. Again: **it is independent on how you connect the inductors !!!**